# AngularJS: Set the model to be = {} again doesn't clear out input type='url'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a fiddler setup, when i click a reset button it should clear out the input controls, this seems to work but not when the input `type='url'`

<kbd>[Here is the fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/martinlondon/rEvXt/)</kbd>

Is there an issue or something that I am not understanding.

When I set

```
$scope.myform = {};
```

This seems to clear out the other input type but the input type='url' isn't being cleared.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue you see happens when you don't have a valid value inside the input[type="url"]. An invalid value just stays in the view (*the input field*) and doesn't get pushed to the scope variable inside ng-model. The variable will be updated only when and if the value is correct.

You can test it by entering a valid value. The reset button will work. If you enter an invalid value it won't.

You can fix it by setting `$scope.myform = null` instead of `$scope.myform = {}`. This will empty the field because the scope variable (*expression*) will be *undefined*. It will be automatically created by Angular once you enter a valid value inside any of the fields.

Comment: Wow, that worked! I am concerned about the =null, as although it works if I try to touch that object in code before teh model updates anything it will be still null, so any harm in this $scope.myform = null and then $scope.myform = {},  this would ensure we have a valid object......???

Comment: No. This won't work because you'll change it before the current $digest phase and at the end it will still be an object.
You can however use $timeout and set the value to an object there or check if the object is null before accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to put a valid url in the 2nd box like `http://www.abc.com`, then the reset button will work.

Comment: Yes I noticed that... a valid URL will allow it to reset

Comment: @Martin You can force to give it a value $scope.bar = '' to clear.

Comment: I don't want to set it to '' as technically it doesn't have any value.

Comment: @Martin It has a value, the value is empty string. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

In order to correctly update the view/model, I would suggest that you explicitly reset the model's properties like so:

```
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.myform = {
        foo: '',
        bar: ''
    };
    $scope.formName.$setPristine();
};
```

Setting 'myform' to an empty object deletes its fields, it doesn't set them to a blank string. It's quite likely angular's cleanup may not be deleting the value the view is referencing, thus the confusion between the application's model and view states.

Hope it helped.

Comment: This is not the issue at cause here. Even trying your answer on the fiddle doesn't yield the expected result.

Comment: Modifying the reset function as I described will cause the two text boxes to reset as the poster requested. I'm not sure what else you were expecting to occur.

Comment: My bad. For some reason, I used `url` and not `bar`. You are right. But the reason why it's not updating is because `type="url"` trigger a validation. As long as the value is not a valid url, the value on the model will be `null`. On the digest cycle after the reset of the model, the value of the model will be `undefined` and not trigger an update to the `$viewValue` of the form. Setting `bar` to an empty string will work (because `''` is neither `undefined` nor `null`) but it's a bit sticky as your model now _has_ a value and is unreliable for form validation unless your check for `''`

Comment: On the part about the disconnect between the model and view without a valid URL, you are entirely correct. However, if you wanted to make sure the reset function works regardless of whether a valid URL has been entered, the model values need to be explicitly cleared.