# Clear invalid input fields in nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have problem with clearing invalid fields from form in angularjs. I've read this threads:

[AngularJS: Set the model to be = {} again doesn't clear out input type='url'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18874019/1081079)

[How to properly clean form with invalid input from AngularJS controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478047/how-to-properly-clean-form-with-invalid-input-from-angularjs-controller)

But it seams that nothing is helping me. I have tried all sugested solutions but I can't make it work.

I have this html, it's the part of the bigger directive template:

```
...

<form name="providerSearch">
   <text-box type="text" ng-model="providerSearchModel.contains.Address" id="SettlementAgentSearch_ProviderSearch_StreetAddress"></input>
   <text-box type="text" ng-model="providerSearchModel.contains.City"   id="SettlementAgentSearch_ProviderSearch_City"></input>
   <text-box type="text" ng-model="providerSearchModel.beginsWith.criteria.Zip" id="SettlementAgentSearch_ProviderSearch_Zip"></input>
</form>

...

<span class="btn btn-link" ng-click="clearSearchFilters()">Clear</span>
```

text-box directive:

```
...
scope: {
   model: '=ngModel',
...
},
...
```

and in directive a have this code:

```
...

link: function(scope,elem,attrs,ctrl) {
   scope.providerSearchModel = {};

   var setProviderModel = function() {
     scope.providerSearchModel = {
        contains: {},
        beginsWith: { filter: 'beginsWith', criteria: {} }
     };
   };

   setProviderModel();

   scope.clearSearchFilters = function() {
       setProviderModel();
   }
}

...
```

So far this was working good, but now I've got requirement to add pattern to `City` field that it can't contains numbers. I added regex to input filed, but now when value is not correct I can't clear that field from UI.

I have tried suggested solutions from other threads but it's not working for me, what am I missing?

Tried changing `scope.clearSearchFilters` to this but it didn't help:

```
scope.clearSearchFilters = function() {
   scope.providerSearchModel = {
      contains: null,
      beginsWith: { filter: 'beginsWith', criteria: null }
   };
}
```

Tried with $setPristine(), no luck:

```
 scope.clearSearchFilters = function() {
   scope.providerSearchModel = {
      contains: null,
      beginsWith: { filter: 'beginsWith', criteria: null }
   };

   scope.providerSearch.$setPristine();
}
```

Also tried setting that field explicitly to null or "" but no success:

```
scope.clearSearchFilters = function() {
   scope.providerSearchModel.City = null; // or scope.providerSearchModel.City = "";
   scope.providerSearchModel.City = {
      contains: null,
      beginsWith: { filter: 'beginsWith', criteria: null }
   };

   scope.providerSearch.$setPristine();
}
```

I have created plunker that reflects my problem, patter is on input that allows only characters so test cases can be: **test** for valid data, and **test1** for invalid...

http://plnkr.co/edit/R5utIfukkOlznoCwi31i?p=preview

Comment: Can you maybe create a plunker?

Comment: Did you try `scope.providerSearchModel = { contains : { City : '' } }` ?

Comment: Yes, I've just tried, but it didn't make any change.

Comment: @imbalid I've added plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited due to comment conversation:**

The problem is combination of displayed vs model value, and "undefined". With the original plunker example, add `'<br/>"{{ providerSearchModel.contains.City }}"'` to your `mainDirective` template (right after the button), and type your two test cases: As you can see with **test1**, the model value is empty (because Angular doesn't let invalid values get to the model).

Just changing the container to be empty will make all the ng-model values undefined, which will not cause view updates.

For just fixing with straight angular, you'll need to set each field value to the empty string or null:

```
var setProviderModel = function() {
    scope.providerSearchModel = {
      contains: {City:null},
      beginsWith: { filter: 'beginsWith', criteria: null }
    };
  };
```

For an clearing an entire form, if you place all your field ng-models in the same container, you can iterate over the properties in the container and set each to null. For example,

```
var clearForm = function() {
    // Set all properties in the ng-model container to null
    for (var prop in scope.providerSearchModel.contains) {
        if (scope.providerSearchModel.contains.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            scope.providerSearchModel.contains[prop] = null;
        }
    } 
    scope.providerSearchModel.beginsWith: { filter: 'beginsWith', criteria: null};
    };
  };
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how to clear tha ViewValue of angular model. As stated in other threads, setting model to null or "" should trigger the change and reset the model but it won't work in my case. I'm not going to use jquery for clearing the values. I will probably add more inputs in that form, so I don't won't to end up with bunch of code just to clear the values using jquery.

Comment: No need to use jquery, it was just an example. Edit: You just need to make sure you set the value to the empty string instead in setProvider: `contains: {City:""},`

Comment: Yes sorry, I wrote that comment too quickly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It seams that it is working in plunker, but as you can see in my question I have more that one field in form. How to clear all the filds in the form in some generic way, what if I end up with 20 - 30 input fields? I will upvote the answer, but I can't mark it as accepted.

Comment: If all your form field ng-models are in some object under the scope (for sake of example, `scope.providerSearchModel.contains`, you could iterate through the properties on that container and set the values to null/empty.

Comment: They are in that exact container :). But why setting the container itself empty won't reset the fields? Ok, I will accept this answer. Thanks for the help. If you could just update your answer with that iteration version it would be great.